# Trying to override product Prestashop 1.7.5

Tags: overriding, prestashop, product

i have difficulties to override class product.php (prestashop 1.7.5).

I want to add a new price field in back-office for products (which admin can use to add extra price to his products.

I've overrided class Product.php (override/classes/product.php) to add this new field :

```
public function __construct($id_product = null, $full = false, $id_lang = null, $id_shop = null, Context $context = null){

        public $service;

        self::$definition['fields']['service'] = [
            'type' => self::TYPE_FLOAT,
            'required' => true, 'size' => 10
        ];

        parent::__construct($id_product, $full, $id_lang, $id_shop, $context);
}
```

And it works, it's in DB, admin can CRUD it.

But, now for calculate price it's a little bit different because i want that the price += service.

So, always in override/classes/product.php, i override public static function priceCalculation() {} with queries to DB (select then update with the result).

But the calculation is done every time I click save on the product sheet in the back office or click on the product sheet in front office (it increments each time) ...

It's not a cache problem, always delete it before trying...

Can just find on the web solutions to add text field, not prices fields...

If anyone can helps :) :)

Thx !

Calculation price (once we're having informations from DB) :
$price = (float) $result['price'] + $result['service'];

And this calcul is good.

query : UPDATE ps_product SET price = $price WHERE id_product = id_product.

Maybe i've to find where i could put this query to avoid this loop...

Comment: Can you also show piece of code that calculates price?

Comment: In fact, im' not sure at all. Do the calculation code has to be in overrided class Product.php ? What about the sql update once calculation is done ?

Now, it looks like this : 
$price = (float) $result['price'] + $result['service'];

And this calcul is good. 

And this is the query UPDATE ps_product SET price = $price WHERE id_product = id_product.

Maybe i've to find where i could put this query to avoid this loop...

Comment: You do not need to save price to the database, all you have to do is `$price = (float) $result['price'] + $result['service'];` If you save price to the database, everytime a product is loaded with price data it will add your service fee which is the problem you have.

Comment: Thx a lot @TheDrot !
It's working fine... I admit that I was convinced that I had  to save the new price in database..Anyway, thanks again !